# Populate WPF treeview in separate thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, monitor

I would appreciate your advice on my problem below:
I need my desktop WPF app to run two separate threads:
First thread: scanning the directory for files.
Second thread: receives FileInfo object from the first thread and puts it as new TreeViewItem in treeview control.
I am trying to solve this using `Monitor` static methods.

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Thread scanThread, treeThread;
    public FileInfo scannedFile;
public object _lock = new object();

    public MainWindow()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
        scanThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Scan));
        treeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(PopulateTree));
}

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath.Text); //I get FolderPath from FolderBrowserDialog
            scanThread.Start(directory);
            treeThread.Start();
}

    public void Scan(object dir)
    {
        DirectoryInfo _directory = (DirectoryInfo)dir;
        foreach (var file in _directory.GetFiles())
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                scannedFile = file;
                Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
                Monitor.Wait(_lock);
            }
        }
    }

public void PopulateTree()
    {
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            if (scannedFile== null)
                return;
            lock (_lock)
            {
                var dirNode = new TreeViewItem();
                dirNode.Items.Add(scannedFile.Name);
                dirNode.Header = scannedFile.Name;
                MyTreeView.Items.Add(dirNode);
                Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
                Monitor.Wait(_lock);
            }
        });
    }
```

Eventually I get random strange results - either no treeview population at all or only last file from folder is added to treeview.
Maybe it's the `Monitor` logic I can't get to work properly, or I should not use public scannedFile variable and pass each `var file in _directory.GetFiles()` in another way to second thread? Thank you in advance!
Update
 I am limited to some basic techniques like Monitor/waithandle so the solution must be made in bounds of these techniques

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend adopting a MVVM pattern if you're using WPF.  You should avoid using code behinds in the window and instead let WPF take care of the monitoring/threading logic.  To do that, you should create a **Model** of your file/directory objects (maybe with a parent class of `FileSystemObject` or something like that).  You would then in your **ViewModel** have some kind of `ObservableCollection<FileSystemObject>` available for rendering in your **View**, which would contain your `TreeView`.    [WPF TreeView ObservableCollection notifying sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293465/wpf-treeview-observablecollection-notifying-sample-code) has a good example of doing something similar to that which you could use as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you Dan, but I am limited to some basic techniques like Monitor/waithandle so the solution must be made in bounds of these techniques.

Comment: What do you mean by *limited*?

Comment: It means that this task must be accomplished using only such sync techniques like Monitor/AutoResetEvent/WaitHandle. Without introducing TPL or MVVM. Just to make it clear - no further scaleablity is foreseen here, just propper use of basic sync mechanisms.

Comment: My suggestion doesn't directly require using TPL, and if you can't use MVVM why are you using WPF?  It seems like a strange limitation to have.