# UWP ObservableCollection notifies View on change

Tags: mvvm, uwp, observablecollection

I want to create an UWP App with a Page, which shows a list of items, which are listed in an ObservableCollection. When I add or remove an item from the list, it should be also be added or removed from the view on the GUI. Or when I change a property of an item, it should also be changed in the view on the GUI. I tried the code from [another page on this platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293465/wpf-treeview-observablecollection-notifying-sample-code) but it did not work.

What is necessary to notify the view (ListView or TreeView), which uses the ObservableCollection as ItemsSource, on changes (new item, removed item, value within item changed) within the ObservableCollection? NotifiyPropertyChanged(<name of ObservableCollection>) does not work in this case, but works on a simple string member.
Can anyone give me a small working example code from Model, View and ViewModel?

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone give me a small working example code from Model, View and ViewModel?

Sure, Please check the following code. And `ObservableCollection` could notify UI Change without `NotifiyPropertyChanged` when add or delete item.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    private ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        GetData();
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            var book = new Book { Name = $" Book{i}", Author = $"Author{i}" };
            Books.Add(book);

        }
        MyListView.ItemsSource = Books;
    }



    private int count;
    private void AddClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        count++;
        Books.Insert(0, new Book { Name = $"NewBook{count}", Author = $"NewAuthor{count}" });
    }

    private void DelClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Books.Count != 0)
        {
            Books.RemoveAt(0);
        }


    }
}
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton
            Click="AddClick"
            Icon="Add"
            Label="Add"
            />
        <AppBarButton
            Click="DelClick"
            Icon="Delete"
            Label="Delete"
            />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
<Grid>

    <ListView x:Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="23,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Author}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't see the different to my code, but I will change your (working!) code to my version and see what is different than in my original code :)

Comment: In my original code I used a TreeView with additional code to be able to define multiple templates. Maybe this code did not update the TreeViewItems. But now I created a ListView which looks very similar to my former TreeView without multiple templates (top items have the same type and contains a list of members with another type which are shown in a ListView within the ListView template of the top item).